# Color HTML tables based on div ID

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django template that I pass a bunch of HTML tables to.  I want to change the background color on certain tables to red, and allow the rest to use the default CSS I've set.  The tables are passed in from my Django view in a dictionary, called `html`, structured like this:

```
{'PanelLabel1': {'Scheduled':[list of html tables],
                 'Unscheduled':[list of html tables]},
 'PanelLabel2': {'Scheduled':[list of html tables],
                 'Unscheduled':[list of html tables]}
}
```

I tried adding a div ID to the unscheduled tables in the template, then changing the color based on the div IDs, but am having trouble getting the div ID to set properly.

My template looks like this:

```
  {% for label,tables in html.items %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="text-center">{{ label | safe }}</h4>
        </div>
        {% for types,table in tables.items %}
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-title text-center"><u>{{types | safe}}</u>
              {% for t in table %}
                {% if types == "Unscheduled" %}
                  <div><p>Here</p></div>
                  <div class="table-responsive Unscheduled" id="Unscheduled">
                    {{ t | safe }}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    {{ t | safe }}
                  </div>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rows = document.getElementById("Unscheduled").getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var cells = document.getElementById("Unscheduled").getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#CC3300";
  };
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I also tried adding an `Unscheduled` class to the div and then styling it using CSS like this:

```
.Unscheduled {
    background: #CC3300;
 }
```

When I look at the developers console, I can see that none of the table divs have an ID (and when I tried using the class, none of them had the `Unscheduled` class), so my javascript to set the table color fails and the CSS doesn't have anything to style.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in setting the div ID/class.  Always looks like this no matter what I do:
[image]

Comment: A simpler and better way to color the tables would be with CSS. You can use the `class` attributes instead of the `id` attributes.

Comment: You should use CSS classes instead of IDs if you want to define some style for your cells. Also the ID attribute should be unique per page.

Comment: @Asaph see the edits I made to my question.  I tried giving the div a special class but that didn't show up in the rendered template either.

Comment: @kdubs your CSS syntax isn't quite right. Remove the `".Unscheduled" ` and change `tr` to `.Unscheduled`. Like this: `.Unscheduled { background: #CC3300; }`.

Comment: @Asaph fixed that but there is still the problem of the class not showing up in the div when rendered.  I added what the code looks like in the developers console.

Comment: And show us what do you hold in your `t` variable. To me it's a bit strange you're assigning the `table-responsive` class to a `div`, but it really depends on what do you have down there in the DOM.

Comment: Then maybe you have a bug in your django template code. Looks like that class should get written to the markup when `types == "Unscheduled"`. Check that conditional.

Comment: @AlexMorozov I added a picture of the rendered code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because you're using the same id "unscheduled" in many instances (view, id's ) and it presents conflict. Try to put a different name to the css class (like "tablestyle" or something) and also, remove the id tag from the div labels leaving just the class parameter. Tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Give each table you want a specific color an id. EXAPMLE: `<table id="yourchoice"></table>` Then use CSS like this `#yourchoice { background-color: red; }` You can choose any color I just like red.